# GitHub checks change the repo it builds on in Azure DevOps

Tags: github, build, azure-devops, continuous-integration, github-actions

Apparently someone was using another repo in Azure DevOps to build a repo in GitHub.

He no longer works here and I have to change this. I do a Pull Request and it builds on another repo. But it does build in the correct repo once I merge the code to master.

The reason I need to change it is that it looks like its building from a YAML that is old and not sure which one.

How do I change where GitHub checks build for a PR? Is it only by removing the build in that other repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find required Azure DevOps pipeline in GitHub - Repo -Settings - Branches-Branches protection rule - Require status checks to pass before merging

[image]

According to the pipeline name, you could find corresponding YAML file in Azure DevOps Project - Repo. Check if this pipeline locates at the wrong repo of Azure DevOps side.

You could directly change the right pipelines if they are listed in GitHub side. Otherwise, you may have to reconfigure GitHub-Azure DevOps Service connection through [Azure Pipeline extension](https://github.com/marketplace/azure-pipelines).

Comment: Unfortunately It seems it was easier just to make a new repo. There were too many permissions involved and it just ended up being easier to create a new repo.